# To find the missing numbers in a comma-separated list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a comma separated lists in cells. All numbers are positive and between 1 and 10.

Example:

if I have in `A1: (2,3,5,6)`, I would like to have missing numbers in `B1:(1,4,7,8,9,10)`.

If `A2: (1,10)`, then I would have in `B2:(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

If `A3: (7)`, then I would have in `B2:(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10)`

I searched for a solution online, but I couldn't find anything similar with comma separated numbers.

I'd be glad if I can have a solution here. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I have Excel 2016.

Comment: Is VBA an option? Doable with a formula but much easier with VBA IMO.

Comment: sure. I know macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a user-defined function that should accomplish this... probably can be optimized.

```
Public Function MissingNumbers(ByVal numberList As String) As String
    Dim temp As String
    temp = Replace(numberList, "(", "")
    temp = Replace(temp, ")", "")
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(temp, ",")
    
    Dim newNumbers As String
    newNumbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        newNumbers = Replace(newNumbers, arr(i) & ",", "")
    Next

    newNumbers = "(" & Left$(newNumbers, Len(newNumbers) - 1) & ")"
    MissingNumbers = newNumbers
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Nice +) fyi Added an alternative using negative filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun demonstrating how to use negative filtering:

```
Function MissingList(ByVal numberList As String) As String
    Dim given: given = Split(Mid(numberList, 2, Len(numberList) - 2), ",")
    Dim series: series = GetSeries()    ' i.e. numbers 1..10
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(given)
        series = Filter(series, given(i), False)    ' << negative filtering
    Next
    MissingList = "(" & Replace(Join(series, ","), "0", "10") & ")"
End Function
```

As `Filter` executes a partial search in the 1..10 series, `10` has to be replaced temporarily by a unique `0`.

**Help function `GetSeries()`**

```
Function GetSeries()
' Purpose: get numbers 1..10
    Const LAST As Long = 10: Const FIRST = 1
    Dim tmp: tmp = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(" & FIRST & ":" & LAST & ")"))
    tmp(LAST) = 0           ' replace 10 by 0 as search item 1 would filter out value 10, too
    GetSeries = tmp
End Function
```