# In excel cell there must be some string values with comma separated ex: apple,orange,grapes,pine apple,Maa

Tags: excel, vba

Example:

if I have in A1: apple,Orange, Grapes I would like to have missing names in B1:Pineapple,Maa.

If A2: Grapes,Pineapple then I would have in B2:Apple,Orange,Maa

I searched for a solution online, but I find same type for missing numbers only. Please help on this

I'd be glad if I can have a solution here. Thanks.

I tired the below:

```
Public Function MissingWords As String
    Dim temp As String
    Temp = Replace (stringList, "") 
    temp = Replace(temp, "") 

    Dim arr As Variant
    Arr = Split (temp, ", ") 

    Dim newstrings As String
    Newstrings = " Apple,Orange,grapes,pineapple, maa"
          
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound (arr) To UBound(arr) 
        Newstrings = Replace (newstrings, arr(I) & ", ", "") 
    Next
    Newstrings = Left$(newstrings, Lena(newstrings) - 1) 
    Missingstrings = newstrings
End function
```

If I applied this in excel getting value error

Comment: I tried to create user defined function, but getting error

Comment: I'm new about this vba so no idea

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65442181/17513917 pls check same like I tried

Comment: Please edit your question, include the code that you have attempted and explain what is not working with your code (include error code and description if it's an error otherwise explain how is it not working)

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and fix your typos... Where did `stringList` come from? and where's your arguments? [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) function requires at least 3 arguments whereas you have 2, please fix that as well. @Sree

Comment: Typos cirrecred and included ine more argument in replace function, still getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function in a worksheet like

```
=GetMissingWordsFromList(A1,"Apple,Orange,Grapes,Pineapple,Maa")
```

And if `A1` is `Pineapple,Maa` you will get `Apple,Orange,Grapes` in return.

Note that this is case sensitive so `Pineapple` and `pineapple` is not considered the same. Also there must not be any spaces after your commas `,` because it cannot handle that.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetMissingWordsFromList(ByVal Words As String, ByVal WordsList As String, Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") As String
    Dim WordsArr() As String
    WordsArr = Split(Words, Delimiter)
    
    Dim WordsListArr() As String
    WordsListArr = Split(WordsList, Delimiter)
    
    Dim RetVal As String
    
    Dim Word As Variant
    For Each Word In WordsListArr
        If Not IsInArray(Word, WordsArr) Then
            RetVal = RetVal & IIf(RetVal = vbNullString, "", ",") & Word
        End If
    Next Word
    
    GetMissingWordsFromList = RetVal
End Function

Private Function IsInArray(ByVal What As String, ByVal InArray As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = IsNumeric(Application.Match(What, InArray, 0))
End Function
```

---

to make it case insensitive (so it will find `Pineapple,Maa` in a list like `apple,orange,grapes,pineapple,maa`) you need to use

```
WordsArr = Split(LCase(Words), Delimiter)
```

and

```
If Not IsInArray(LCase(Word), WordsArr) Then
```

instead.

Comment: Getting value error

Comment: I have doubt here you don't mention Newstrings = " Apple,Orange,grapes,pineapple, maa" These in code. Is that not needed

Comment: @Sree no the newstrings is what you submit as second parameter in `GetMissingWordsFromList(A1,"Apple,Orange,Grapes,Pineapple,Maa")` hardcoded data in VBA is a bad idea, therefore a parameter is used. And I tested the code it works if you use it as explained. Please check again and do exactly as described.

Comment: Superr... I got it... Thank you so much for this breif coding.. Thanks alot

Comment: Note that you can also put that string `"Apple,Orange,Grapes,Pineapple,Maa"` into a cell e.g. `C1` and link to it in your formula `=GetMissingWordsFromList(A1, $C$1)`

Answer (score 0):

the last line for your function should be

```
MissingWords=NewStrings
```

Now, your function always returns nothing.
Missingstrings is not defined in the function.

Comment: Did that change.. Still getting error